# fopen падает с segfault. си

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

Прoграмма читает файловую систему proc, а именно должнa читать stat файлы процессов. У меня на 3 процессе всё падает по segmentation fault. Падает на fopen(), когда fopen вызывает malloc; не могу понять в чем дело.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define MAX_LENGTH_FILENAME 120

typedef struct proc_info
{
    int pid;
    char *name;
    int ppid;
} proc_info;

typedef struct Node
{
    proc_info *info;
    struct Node *next;
    struct Node *prev;
} Node;

typedef struct List
{
    size_t size;
    struct Node *head;
    struct Node *tail;
} List;

List *createList()
{
    List *tmp =  (List *) malloc (sizeof(List));
    tmp->head = NULL;
    tmp->tail = NULL;
    tmp->size = 0;
    return tmp;
}

void copy_proc_info(proc_info *dst, const proc_info *src)
{
    size_t len = strlen(src->name);
    dst->pid = src->pid;
    dst->ppid = src->ppid;
    dst->name = (char *) malloc(len + 1);
    if (NULL == dst->name)  { fprintf(stderr,"Error get new memory.\nNot create new char*!\n"); }
    else
    {
        strncpy(dst->name, src->name, len + 1);
    }
}

void push_back(List *list, const proc_info *info)
{
    int rezult = 0;
    Node *tmp = (Node *) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if (NULL == tmp)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error get new memory.\nNot create new Node!\n");
        return;
    }
    tmp->next = NULL;
    tmp->prev = list->tail;
    copy_proc_info(tmp->info, info);
    if (list->tail) { list->tail->next = tmp; }
    list->tail = tmp;
    if (list->head == NULL)
    {
        list->head = tmp;
    }
    list->size++;
}

bool cat_stat_file(const char *dir_name, struct proc_info *info)
{
    errno = 0;
    bool rezult = false;
    char buf[MAX_LENGTH_FILENAME+1+11];
    sprintf(buf, "/proc/%s/stat", dir_name);
        printf("%s", buf);
    FILE *f = fopen(buf, "r"); //погибает здесь на 3 вызове
    if (errno && (NULL == f))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error open file %s\n", buf);
        perror("");
    }
    else
    {
        fscanf(f,"%d %s %*c %d", &info->pid, &buf, &info->ppid);
        printf("%s\n", buf);
        if (errno)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error read file %s.\n", dir_name);
            perror("");
            errno = 0;
        }
        else 
        {
            size_t len = strlen(buf) + 1;
            info->name = (char *) malloc(len);
            strncpy(info->name, buf, len);
            rezult = true;
        }
        fclose(f);
        if (errno)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error close file %s.\n", dir_name);
            perror("");
            errno = 0;
        }
    }
    return rezult;
}

List *get_dir_list(const char *dir_name)
{
    struct proc_info *dir_list = NULL;
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *entry;
    List *list = createList();
    if ((dir  = opendir(dir_name)) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opendir %s\n", dir_name);
        perror("");
        errno = 0;
        return NULL;
    }
    while ( (entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL) 
    {
        if (errno)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error read_dir %s\n", dir_name);
            perror("");
            errno = 0;
            continue;
        }
        if ( (entry->d_type != DT_DIR) || (strlen(entry->d_name) > 5) || !strtol(entry->d_name, NULL, 0))
            {continue;}
        proc_info *info = (struct proc_info *) malloc(sizeof(proc_info));
        if (cat_stat_file(entry->d_name, info)) push_back(list, info);
        else free(info);
    };
    return list;
}

int main()
{
    List *list = get_dir_list("/proc");
    //destroyList(&list);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Выделенную ранее память где-то портите (например, пишете больше, чем выделили) или дважды делаете free одного и того же блока.

Comment: @avp до free даже не доходит. вот и ломаю голову.
valgrind шоворит следующее
==10101== 1 errors in context 1 of 2:
==10101== Invalid write of size 4
==10101==    at 0x804889F: copy_proc_info (in /home/super/step/parent/a.out)
==10101==    by 0x804896E: push_back (in /home/super/step/parent/a.out)
==10101==    by 0x8048CBE: get_dir_list (in /home/super/step/parent/a.out)
==10101==    by 0x8048D0F: main (in /home/super/step/parent/a.out)
==10101==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
но не хватает опыта чтобы всё это понять. я только учусь.

Comment: Размер `MAX_LENGTH_FILENAME` может маловат? Лучше для путей использовать `PATH_MAX`, определенную в `stdlib.h` (точнее в `/usr/include/linux/limits.h`, но подтягивается и через `stdlib`). / Динамически выделять `proc_info` явно лишнее. Эту информацию можно разместить сразу в `Node` / Имя процесса может содержать пробелы (Вы что-то такое ранее уже спрашивали), но к счастью, оно заключено в скобки. Лучше прочесть весь файл (точнее его единственную строку) `fgets()`-ом и локализовать имя там, вызывая `strchr`/`strrchr` для поиска скобок. ppid тогда можно прочесть `sscanf`-ом, от правой скобки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В функции `push_back` вы забыли выделить память под `tmp->info`.

```
tmp->next = NULL;
tmp->prev = list->tail;
tmp->info = (proc_info *) malloc(sizeof(proc_info)); // <----- здесь
copy_proc_info(tmp->info, info);
```

Comment: List *get_dir_list(const char *dir_name)
{
......
proc_info *info = (struct proc_info *) malloc(sizeof(proc_info));
  if (cat_stat_file(entry->d_name, info)) push_back(list, info);
  else free(info);
}
@kmv она выделена в get_dir_list, а в push_back передается указатель

Comment: @rubeno4ka под `info` память выделена, согласен, а под `tmp->info` - нет.

Comment: точно вы правы, спасибо. теперь функция copy_proc_info в принципе не требуется. tmp->info = info. спасибо за помощь.